# NLP Negex Taking Too Long

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, negation

I'm currently trying to find entities that are negated.

I have the following code, but since my string is too long, it's taking forever to run.

Is there any way I can optimize this? I haven't found a good solution that's working.

```
nlp.add_pipe("negex",last=True)
doc = nlp(my string)
fmt_str = "{:<22}| {:<10}"
print(fmt_str.format("Entity", "Is negated"))
for entity in doc.ents:
    print(fmt_str.format(entity.text, entity._.negex))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: I recommend the spaCy speed FAQ if you haven't seen it before. https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/8402

Comment: In general I think more information is required to help you though. How many texts do you have? What does your pipeline look like? What does the whole structure of your code look like?